# Matplotlib skipping some values in the y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, python-3.7, yaxis

I wrote a python code that runs matplotlib and creates a graph on the basis of 2 lists, one for x axis and another for the y one..

The lists are as follows..

```
lst = ['interest', 'anticipation', 'submission', 'sadness', 'anger'] 
num = ['3', '2', '1', '1', '1']
```

Now when I run the following code

```
plt.figure("Top_5_keyword_Group")
plt.bar(revLst(lst),revLst(num), color="green")
plt.pause(0.05)
time.sleep(2)
plt.show()
```

It outputs the following graph:

[image: Click to see the graph]

If you see the graph, Its missing a zero in the start and not only zero, but any other value that not in the y-axis list like if the list was `[1,3,5,9,2]`, I would have had `4,6,7,8` missing.. which somewhat destroys the aim of the graph..

Is there any easy way to fix this code?

my python version is 3.7

Comment: convert the `num` list to numbers, because they're currently strings. `num = list(map(int, num))`

Comment: Thanks... How the hell did I missed that??

Comment: Brain needs more coffee or more sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you define *num* as list of **strings**?
A more natural solution is to define it as a list of **integers**.

```
lst = ['interest', 'anticipation', 'submission', 'sadness', 'anger']
num = [3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then, running:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

plt.figure("Top_5_keyword_Group")
plt.bar(lst[::-1], num[::-1], color="green")
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator())
plt.show()
```

I got the following picture:

[image]

Note that I added *MultipleLocator* (with default *base == 1*) to have
*y* tick labels only on integer values.

Additional remark: The documentation claims that the first parameter of
*plt.figure* can be a string and then it is set as the  title, but at least
in my case this title hasn't appeared.

If the same is in your environment, change the respective fragment of code to:

```
ax = fig.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator()))
ax.set_title("Top_5_keyword_Group")
```